# App to convert .h264 video on ipad to watch in "Photos" app?

Tags: ipad, applications, video, photos.app, h.264

I have a video clip with extention ".h264" on my online storage, and i want to save it in "Photos" app on my iPad and watch it there... Is there an app for that? I think it might need to be converted to a playable format even before putting it in Photos. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Uploading the video to your iPad will place the video in the app called "videos". I believe you don't have to convert the file because iOS supports .h264